# Where do I put my own xml code in activity_main using Androids default tab application

Tags: android, xml, android-fragments, android-viewpager

This is the activity_main.xml layout for Androids default tab application:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".activities.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/appbar_padding_top"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

    <!-- When I add my own view here and use match_parent, it fills ENTIRE screen, even over the Toolbar. The ViewPager right above does not do this. Why? -->

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

I am trying to add my own buttons/textviews/etc to my `activity_main.xml` but I do not know where to add them. The `android.support.v4.view.ViewPager` uses `match_parent` although it does not fit the whole screen, it expands across the entire screen besides the `Toolbar` area at the top. However, whenever I add my own view underneath the `android.support.v4.view.ViewPager`, lets say `RelativeView` and set it to `match_parent`, it expands OVER the `Toolbar`. This led me to believe that I should put my contents inside the `ViewPager` tags but that does not work either.

Where should I put my views so that they are not overlapping the `Toolbar`?

Comment: in another file - a layout for fragment, then you should implement Adapter which would provide the fragments for ViewPager ...

Comment: @Selvin I want to add content to my Main Activity though, not for my fragment. For example I want a button on my main activity that stays there across all tabs.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your `ViewPager` in an `RelativeLayout` and you can add the view child also.

Here is the code snippet which may help you-

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:text="I am clickable" />

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/button"
            android:background="@color/colorNeutral"
            android:layout_above="@+id/button2" />

        <Button
            android:layout_marginBottom="56dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:text="I am clickable too" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```